# How many anagrams of a word exist

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many anagrams of the word ''Combinatorics'' exist such that a consonant is in the middle.

Comment: Does capitalization matter? Have you tried working it out for a smaller word? Have you tried setting a few consonants in the middle? What do you think is important in solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shall assume one does not care about capitalization.

We then have these letters:

`2 C
2 O
1 M
1 B
2 I
1 N
1 A
1 T
1 S`

The **total** number of permutations is $\frac{12!}{2!2!2!}$

The number of words with a *vowel* in the middle is the number of words with an `O` in the middle plus the number of words with an `A` in the middle plus the ones with an `I` in the middle. How many words are there with an `A` in the middle? $\frac{11!}{2!2!2!}$. How many words have an `O` in the middle? $\frac{11!}{2!2!}$. With a similar train of thought, we get that there are $\frac{11!}{2!2!}$ words with an `I` in the middle.

Then the number of words with a consonant in the middle is

$$\frac{12!}{2!2!2!} - \frac{11!}{2!2!2!} - 2\frac{11!}{2!2!}$$